# How do I stop VMware / Vagrant from attempting to create NFS shares?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-player, nfs, vagrant

I am trying to use VMware instead of VirtualBox to run my VMs. Host:Windows10, Guest: CentOS7. I am using PuPHPet to create the required vagrant files, but whichever file system I choose, Default, NFS, SMB or RSync vagrant up always tries to mount NFS shared folders and fails. I believe that Windows doesn't support NFS so it doesn't surprise me that it fails, but I can't find a way of disabling this. In my Vagrant file I have added:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  eval File.read("#{dir}/puphpet/vagrant/Vagrantfile-#{data['target']}")
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
  config.vm.synced_folder "B:\\Web\\www.example.com\\public_html", "/home/example/public_html", type: "rsync"
end
```

and this mounts and syncs the folder, which I presumed would negate the need to mount the NFS shares, but after that I still get:

```
==> example: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/b/Web/www.example.com/public_html/ => /home/example/public_html
==> example: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> example: Preparing to edit nfs mounting file.
==> example: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o vers=3,udp,vers=3,udp,nolock 192.168.246.1:/B/Web/www.example.com /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

mount.nfs: Connection refused
```

I'm not sure why the IP 192.168.246.1 is being refereed to as that's not in any config file that I've searched.

Comment: Windows 10 absolutely supports NFS.  You do need to enable the optional feature (Services for NFS) though.  [Background](https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/)

Comment: I've enabled services for NFS, done a reboot and it still fails. I've redone the PuPHPet files and set the shared folder type to NFS. Vagrant up, but it still hangs, the only difference I see is this line```mount -o vers=3,udp,vers=3,udp,nolock 192.168.246.1:/B/Web/www.example.com /mnt/vagrant-folder1```